# How can I read the messages multiple time from kafka with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, java-17

I am using a Spring Boot Application to test microservices. I want to read the last X message from a topic multiple times. (e.g: multiple test scenarios want to check whether the microservice has sent the correct message to kafka topic or not) How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka consumers work by tracking an offset for each partition in a topic. This offset points to the record that the consumer should read next. The consumer offset (which records what messages have been read) is managed per consumer group. This means that different consumer groups can read the same set of messages independently without interfering with each other.

For your case, each test scenario could have its own unique consumer group. This would allow each test scenario to read from the topic from the start or any specified offset, independent of the other tests. So the typical test would be like this:

```java
void thisIsTheTest() {
    // GIVEN
    var subscription = kafkaTestUtil.subscribeTo(topic, groupId)

    // WHEN
    // execute your scenarion

    // THEN
    var messages = subscription.poolLast(x);
}
```

You need to implement subscribing and pooling logic in some test util class.

If you want to read the last `X` messages, you would need to find the latest offset and then seek to that offset minus `X`. But please note that retrieving the last `X` messages from a topic may not be straightforward due to the topic being comprised of partitions, each with its own offset, and messages being spread around partitions according to the partition key. So it's not really clear how to calculate the last `X` messages.

A simple way to streamline this process is to allocate a single partition for each topic within your testing (ONLY TESTING) environment. This will make it easy to retrieve the most recent X messages. But actually, this option may not suit everyone.

p.s. you can read more about consumer groups here:
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_group.id
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#consumer-groups